# Undefined X-access-token (jwt)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

Whenever I try to call the token from my backend (express) I'm getting x-access-token as undefined in the network params after i want to check if a user is authenticated. Ive tried adding the "bearer" text inside the getItem from local storage function, but it only changes the output to NaN. Is there anyway to fix this?

**users.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const userModel = require('../models/userModel')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

const verifyJWT = (req,res,next) =>{
  const existingToken = req.headers['x-access-token']

  if(!existingToken){
    res.send('No token exists')
  }
  if(existingToken){
    jwt.verify(existingToken, 'PODFSPFKNCXJN-QWWEQWEQW-SADJKDWPU-WQKQLWEWQ', (err, username) => {
      if(err){
        res.json({auth: false, message: 'auth failed'})
      }
      else{
        req.body.username = username;
        next();
      }

    })
  }
  else{
    res.json({error, message:error})
  }
}

router.get('/userValid', verifyJWT, (req,res)=>{
    res.send('YOU ARE AUTHORISED')
})

// submit users to db
router.post('/register', (req,res) =>{

  // checking if user already exists
  userModel.findOne({username: req.body.username}, async (err, user) =>{
    // handle any errors
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    // if username already exists in db
    if(user){
      res.send('user already exists')
    }
    if(!user){
      try {
        // hashing password before submitted to db
        const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)

        // new instance of user model to be mutated    
        const User = new userModel({
            // grabbing user register data and pushing to mongo
            username: req.body.username,
            password: hashedPass
        })
        const newUser = await User.save()
        console.log("Succesfully Registered: " + newUser) 
        res.json({user: req.body.username, message: 'Successfully Registered'})
      } 
      catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  })
})

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const user = await userModel.findOne({ username: req.body.username });

  try{
      const match = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)

      const accessToken = jwt.sign(JSON.stringify(user), 'PODFSPFKNCXJN-QWWEQWEQW-SADJKDWPU-WQKQLWEWQ')

      if(match){
          res.json({authenticated: true, username: req.body.username,accessToken: accessToken })
          // should return true if passwords match
          console.log(match);
      } else {    
          res.json({authenticated: false, message: "Invalid Credentials" })
      }
  } catch(error) {
      res.send({authenticated: false, message: 'No user exists'})
  }
})


module.exports = router;
```

**login.js (react)**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Axios from "axios";
import axios from 'axios';

const Login = () => {
    const [logUsername, setLogUsername] = useState('')
    const [logPassword, setLogPassword] = useState('')
    const [loggedInStatus, setLoggedInStatus] = useState(false)



    const loginUser = () => {
        // testing if connected to express route
        Axios({
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                username: logUsername,
                password: logPassword,
            },
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/users/login'
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            if(res.data.authenticated === false){
                alert('invalid username/passoword')
                setLoggedInStatus(false)
            }
            else{
                alert('Successfully logged in')
                //window.location.href = '/homepage'
                localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token)
                setLoggedInStatus(true)
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

    const userAuthenticated = () => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/users/userValid', {
        headers: {
            "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")
        }})
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Login Page</h1><br />
            <label>username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value={logUsername} onChange={(e) => setLogUsername(e.target.value)} required></input><br></br>

                <label>passowrd</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value={logPassword} onChange={(e) => setLogPassword(e.target.value)} required></input><br />
                <button onClick={loginUser}>sign up</button>         

            <br />
            <Link to="/" type="button"> register here</Link>

            {loggedInStatus && (
                <button onClick={userAuthenticated}>Check if Authenticated</button>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: First check that localStorage has stored the value of the token if the value is not stored for that reason axios doesn't send the value because the undefined values are omitted, also in the express app exposes your custom headers using cors package.

Comment: Thanks so much! I logged the set local storage and I realised i forgot i named my token variable as 'accessToken' instead of 'token'

Comment: Great, somethings those silly errors happen.